# Apache mod auth_ldap won't work if ssl turned on

Tags: apache, authentication, ssl, openldap

Here is the full story with details below, I'd appreciate any suggestions.

I have a web server that I need to enable apache auth with ldap to certain resources. I also have openldap server that I can authenticate with. The openldap has both ports 389 and 636 enabled and there is a self signed cert installed on openldap. The web server has openldap client configured and can ID users. If I test connection to openldap from web server using this string:

```
openssl s_client -connect openldapserverIP:636 -showcerts
```

I getting response with all correct info.

In the web server config I've added this:

```
<Directory /www/protect>
Order deny,allow
Deny from All
AuthName "identity"
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthLDAPBindAuthoritative off
AuthLDAPUrl ldap://openldapIP/ou=People,dc=mydomain,dc=org?uid
AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=ldapreadonlyuser,dc=mydomain,dc=org"
AuthLDAPBindPassword "somethinghere"
AuthLDAPGroupAttribute memberUid
Require ldap-attribute  myAttribute=800
Require ldap-attribute myAttribute=820
Satisfy any
LogLevel debug
</Directory>
```

and it works.

Then if I enable secure connection, changing the connection string to:

```
AuthLDAPUrl ldaps://openldapIP/ou=People,dc=mydomain,dc=org?uid TLS
```

or

```
AuthLDAPUrl ldap://openldapIP:636/ou=People,dc=mydomain,dc=org?uid TLS
```

it does not work.

Here is the error log:

```
auth_ldap authenticate: user x authentication failed; URI / [LDAP: ldap_simple_bind() failed][Can't contact LDAP server] (not authoritative)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
LDAPVerifyServerCert Off
```

at a global level in your Apache configuration. That's because your certificate is self-signed.

Comment: It would be safer to use romank's answer, and just tell Apache that the LDAP server's self-signed cert is the one to trust. Self-signed or not, it's the one your authentic LDAP server should be presenting. Turning verification off would let Apache happily connect to an impostor LDAP server using some other certificate and pretending to be yours.

Answer (score 1):

Put your CA cert and ldap servers cert in `/etc/pki/mycerts/certs-bundle.pem` and add parameter `LDAPTrustedGlobalCert CA_BASE64 /etc/pki/mycerts/certs-bundle.pem` to your httpd.conf